# Eclipse History for non java files

Tags: eclipse

I noticed that not all file types end up in Eclipse history. Is there a way to edit the preferences so that all file types get the history treatment? *.js, *.jsp, *.xhtml, *.css...

EDIT: I since had many instances of history not being saved correctly. In this example, it was a java file that i made quick modifications

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, can you double-check? In Eclipse Helios, I can create e.g. a text file in a Java project and it is correctly tracked by the History mechanism.

Comment: Works for me as well. There aren't any preferences to control the files stored in the workspace history as far as I know. You might want to try [resetting your local history](http://breathingtech.com/2009/how-to-reset-workspace-in-eclipse/) ...

Comment: I verified a few files I touched and the ARE in history. However, when I goofed up with perforce last week merging, I made a last ditch effort to recover a day's worth of work, there were files with no history at all. *.xhtml, *.vm, some others I think. Maybe a fluke, but now i periodically check history. It is good to hear Eclipse is supposed to archive all files indiscriminately.  I am running STS 2.5.1 bundled with eclipse 3.6.something